# Caching a Partial View Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm calling my partial view using jQuery Load

I tried using `[OutputCache(Duration = 10, VaryByParam = "*")]`  but I have the same result 
I get 200 Ok Instead of 304 not modified

```
setInterval(function () {
    $("#ETLjobs").load('@Url.Action("indexp","JobsETL")');
}, 5000);
```

My controller is

```
[DonutOutputCache(Duration = 500)]
public ActionResult Indexp()
{
    var x = db.BIOGetETLJobs();
    var  y = from xx in x
                where xx.etat!="Completed"
                select xx;
    return PartialView(y);
}
```

by the way how to change the load action to a long polling ??

the cashe is working actually i get 200 OK (From Cache)

Comment: have you done something like $.ajaxSetup({cache:false}); ?  That will prevent your caching from working I believe as each request is rendered unique

Comment: No ,the cashe works for result type application/json but it doesnt work for Text/html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using ASP.NET output caching, you will always get a 200 OK, even when the content is served from the server's output cache. That is the intended behaviour.

The server does not try to determine whether what you have cached locally is older than what is in the server's output cache, thus does not return 304 Not Modified.

Comment: yes  i figured out but it returns 304 not modified and 200 OK (From cache) ,i didnt understand why not return the same response

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns 304 not modified and 200 OK (From cache)"? When does it return what?

Comment: one partial view 304 not modified  and onother one is 200 OK (From cache) in the same page,how can i force the result to be 304 not modified